# In Smarty display method not working

Tags: smarty

Display method not working only print "kamal" not print "maisuriya"

Please help me?

```
print("kamal");
$tpl->display('default_layout'. $config['tplEx']);
print("Maisuriya");
```

Comment: Is something failing in the `$tpl->display` call? Is there any error output?

Answer (score 4):

If you're not seeing any error messages, you might want to activate them (temporarily) with `ini_set("display_errors", true); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

If you're using Smarty3 run a `$tpl->testInstall();` after you've setup Smarty to see if everything is ok. Then check if your template exists with `$tpl->templateExists('default_layout'. $config['tplEx']);`

My guess is either the requested file doesn't exist, or the template contains syntax errors, or some function called within the template did not execute properly. But without the error message, I can't tell.